# Spring batch job parameters are not overriding even if I change in job parameter validator

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I've a job parameter validator where I've mentioned compulsory and optional parameters. I run the batch and it executes correctly.

```
@Bean
    public JobParametersValidator validator() {

    String[] compulsoryParameters; //here I've created my compulsory parameters
    String[] optionalParams ; //here I've created my optional parameters

    return new DefaultJobParametersValidator(compulsoryParameters, optionalParams);
}
```

Now, If I remove an item from compulsory parameter and if I run it again. It still asks to pass the same parameter.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException: The JobParameters contains keys that are not explicitly optional or required: [incrementerId]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.DefaultJobParametersValidator.validate(DefaultJobParametersValidator.java:107)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:126)
```

**Batch Configuration**

Compulsory / Optional parameters are configured in application.properties

> mybatch.batch.compulsoryParameters=name
>
> mybatch.batch.optionalParameters=inputNumber

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.something.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.something.*")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableCaching
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mybatch.batch", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class BatchConfig {

    /**
     * Configuration settings for the validator
     */
    private String[] compulsoryParameters;
    private String[] optionalParameters;

    /**
     * Default validator for Spring Batch
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public JobParametersValidator validator() {

        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (optionalParameters != null) {
            Collections.addAll(tempList, optionalParameters);
        }

        // Adding the run.id parameter for enabling the rerun batches
        tempList.add("run.id");
        String[] optionalParams = new String[tempList.size()];
        optionalParams = tempList.toArray(optionalParams);

        return new DefaultJobParametersValidator(compulsoryParameters, optionalParams);
    }


}
```

**Note**: All the job details are persisting in database.

Comment: Can you remove `@EnableCaching` and then run it? Also i would say make `ignoreUnknownFields` as `true` and then check if you are getting a old record somehow?

Comment: Nope ! I've tried it. I'm getting the same problem

Comment: What about old record check?

Comment: What do you mean by old record check?
My question is,
1. I've defined JobParameter Validator with 3 compulsory/optional paramters.
2. I ran the job with the 3 parameters - successful
3. I've removed 1 parameter and now I've 2 parameters in JPValidator.
4. I ran the job with 2 parameters - job failed 
It expects the third parameter which I've not mentioned in my project.

Comment: @nmkyuppie did you find the solution for this one now ?

Comment: @shazakham Nope. I just changed it as a REST Service and attached the job parameters with request.

Answer (score -2):

As the error states clearly every parameter either has to be part of `compulsoryParameters` or `optionalParams`.

For example for my job pass three parameters START_DATE, RUN_DATE and END_DATE. I have included all in `compulsoryParameters` if i remove one from this list and continue to pass then it error out saying there is one key in parameters that is not explicitly added to either of the list.

```
@Bean
    public JobParametersValidator validator() {
        String[] compulsoryParameters = {"START_DATE", "RUN_DATE", "END_DATE"}; //here I've created my compulsory parameters
        String[] optionalParams = {""}; //here I've created my optional parameters

        return new DefaultJobParametersValidator(compulsoryParameters, optionalParams);
    }
```

So try adding all the parameters passed by adding either to `compulsoryParameters` or `optionalParams`. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't answer my question. In the above example previously I had incrementerId as Compulsory/Optional parameter. After the first run I removed it from code. I got that exception after removing it from compulsory/optional Params.@amit

Comment: @nmkyuppie Did you continue to pass it in `JobParameters` after removing from the compulsory/optional Params?

Comment: No! I've removed it in comp/opt params. So I didn't pass it. Still it asks for the incrementerId

Comment: can you upload all of the batch config? also i dont see code where you add Compulsory/Optional parameter?